# Is Firebase free version (spark) is sufficinet for project with almost 1000 active users per month?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use firebase for backend as a service for my college project.
Docs are well elaborated but I have doubt in understanding what is the meaning of 10,000 phone auth per month. If one user login multiple times in a month is it considered as 1 auth or the number of times the user login.
Also, what is the limit of email authentications?
If I use sign-in with google or facebook is that is going to be counted in email authentication?

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly for questions about billing.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firebase Authentication's phone provider it is common that the user only signs in once, and not each time they start the app.

There is no documented limit on email authentication calls, although there is (undocumented) abuse protection.

Comment: Also one small thing..whenever I am exporting data, is that is going to be counted in daily read counts?

Comment: I assume you're talking about Cloud Firestore. Any time a document is read on the server on your behalf, that will count as a charged read. This applies to both reads that you trigger through the API, but also to reads that you trigger another way, such as through backups, or through the console.